# Strange issue with Laravel's flash session

Tags: php, laravel

I'm encountering a very strange issue and couldn't find anything about it. I'm trying a very simple thing, using a flash message in Laravel to display a message to the user if a condition didn't met.

Basically this is the controller code i'm using:

```
        Session::flash('error', 'error message');
        return redirect()->back();

//      this didn't work either
//      return redirect()->action('Controller@method', $var)->with('error', ['error message']);
```

The thing is, it IS working when I var_dump the session in the view, but not without it. This is the view:

```
{{ Session::get('error') }} // does not work
{{ dd(Session::get('error')) }} // works!
```

It is a very simple thing, but I don't know why it goes wrong.

Any helpers around? :) Thanks!

Comment: And what you get while you do this `var_dump(Session::all());` ?

Comment: I get all the session of course, including the flashed one. It just doesn't display it, with or without prior if 'Session::has('error')' condition

Comment: Can you do this ? `@if (Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('error') }}</div>
@endif`

Comment: Yes that's what i'm always trying initially to get it working, I got it working in other pages in the same method... Does it perhaps have something to do with sending a request to another method and then calling back or redirect to the original one? I think that it still counts as a request, but that's like typical workflow

Comment: I too think the same, Is it working good when you do this in controller `return redirect()->action('Control..` and have `@if (Session::has('error')) <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('error') }}</div> @endif` in your view ?

Comment: It should be, it doesn't display it regardless of the if condition... And the exact same workflow worked great so far in other pages... Don't know why I can only dump it, so strange!

Comment: For instance, can you clear all the files inside your `sessions` folder ?

Comment: Hmm I think you just gave me an idea to try the 'session()->regenerate()' method and it seems that it's working that way! I don't know if it's a good practice, but it works :))

Comment: Thanks, I have posted an answer of what i said `(As comment is not the  good way for the future readers ) :)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall debug in this way

Clear all the files in your `sessions` folder

In your controller you can create flash message using any of the given two ways

```
 Session::flash('error', 'error message');
 return redirect()->back();
```

or

```
  return redirect()->action('Controller@method', $var)->with('error', ['error message']);
```

Then in your blade

```
@if (Session::has('error')) 
<div class="alert alert-info">
    {{ Session::get('error') }}
</div> 
@endif
```

Comment: Well spotted, it worked but i'm still not sure though whether it's a good long-term solution, it doesn't quite fit in my head to regenerate the session only in a particular method... But I don't want to scream "bug!" :)

Comment: Ah, I too agree, are you unsetting  or removing all the sessions after its usage ?

Comment: Actually my current sessions are very minimalistic so I doubt it gets overloaded, i'm clearing everything I don't need and i'm very cautious about adding more other than flashes... Could be that setting a session database would eliminate such behavior? It worked great in Codeigniter, where I came from. :)

Comment: Though i use `Laravel` i feel that `Codeigniter` is far better in such cases. And if the sessions get overloaded, then it will react different for different users :)

Comment: Coming from Codeigniter, i'm not very happy to hear that. :) It seems that Laravel does have such implementation [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#database-sessions). I'm guessing that you have already tried it though hehe...
I'll keep an eye on that, thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Ha ha, I too feel the same.. Yeah i go thought there also .. You are welcome mate :)